# Angular 2 with angular2-google-map

Tags: angular, angular2-google-maps

i would like to ask question about angular2-google-map in angular 2. I have followed the instruction in https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html. Running 'ng serve' give the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf1pM.jpg)

I have digging around, but angular 2 does not have SystemJS to configure the node_module.

Comment: try `npm install` before `ng serve`

Comment: let me try first.

Comment: Thanks, that solve issues with angular/core. but then it return the error 'has no exported member 'AgmCoreModule' ''.

Comment: Could you share your project ? You can see a working example with System.js here : http://plnkr.co/edit/YX7W20?p=preview

Comment: how to share my project, i am still new to stackoverflow and angular2 architecture, sorry for troubling you

Comment: Share it on a Github account, for example

Comment: https://github.com/AbdulAfiq/Angular2Map.git , sorry im late, still new to github too.

Answer (score 0):

After night of digging around, i have found the answer. The following step is the fix for "has no exported member 'AgmCoreModule' ":

Inside package.json:

```
"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.0"
```

In command line:

```
npm install
```

The [Getting Started](https://angular-maps.com/docs/getting-started.html) only showed to install package after the creation of project. Since that i'm still new to this, the error is unseen by me. Thank you  Karbos 538 and Roman C. for helping me in Stackoverflow.

Comment: i hope my post will be a great help to others who are learning Angular 2

Answer (score 0):

To get the angular2-google-map now called @agm/core working it is important to update the **selector tags**. The author has not yet updated the docs (in this moment of the post).

**BEFORE last update:**

npm install angular2-google-maps --save

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

**NOW after latest update**

npm install @agm/core --save

```
<sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <sebm-google-map-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</sebm-google-map>
```

**Example setup:**

*file: google-maps.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-maps',
  templateUrl: './google-maps.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-maps.component.css'],
})

export class GoogleMapsComponent implements OnInit {
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;

constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

*file: google-maps.component.html*

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

*file: google-maps.component.css*

```
.sebm-google-map-container {
  height: 300px;
}
```

*file: app.module.ts*

```
import { AgmCoreModule } from '@agm/core';
@NgModule({imports: [AgmCoreModule.forRoot()}]]
```